# how to save one column value based on id column in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to save model id along with other format characters into another column, based on the model id being automatically created. For example,

For example, I have column name  formated_id in shipment model, and want set its value to "easter" + ID which is automatically generated. How could I achieve that? Thanks.

```
class Shipment(models.Model):

    formated_id = models.CharField("formatedid",max_length= 50)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the formated_id after the instance is first saved, which is when the primary key is created. Something along the lines of the following (untested) code should do the trick

```
class Shipment(models.Model):

    formated_id = models.CharField("formatedid",max_length= 50)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
       self.formated_id = 'easter{}'.format(self.pk)
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it seems cannot call super().save(*args, **kwargs) two times.